# Programmatically get Google Datastore record count and used storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-python, gcloud-python

I need to get Google Datastore usage statistics - storage usage, and record count for my application.

At the moment I only can count fetch all items and count them. But I have no idea how I can get storage amount used.

Is there any reports API I can use? (Like Google Apps report api)

PS. I use [gcloud-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python) library to access Datastore.

Edited:

Thank you Andrei - Angels Like Reb

That's how I did it:

```
from gcloud import datastore
stat = list(datastore.Query('__Stat_Total__').fetch())[0]
print "bytes", stat['bytes']
print "count", stat['count']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [statistics queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/admin).